# How to store private data on blockchain?

Tags: security, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm writting DApp on Ethereum (Solidity) and I need to find a solution how to store a private data on blockchain, when I also need to proceed them somehow. If it is only about storing, I can use some normal encrypting, but the problem is that I need to read the data IN the smart contract and proceed it somehow too.

Let's say:

1) I want to send some private number to a blockchain.

2) I need to check if the privete number is bigger than the last stored private number and smaller than the second last stored number.

```
if (storage[n] < y < storage[n-1]) storage.push(y);
```

3) If yes, I want to store it privately.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use a data structure with two entries e.g. a tuple, with the first entry to use as the counter (i.e. to take care of `check if the private number is bigger than the last stored private number` part, and the second entry to store an encrypted data, one to use as a counter.

```
y = new Dapp(sno, value)
# compare y's sno with the record, store private data in value
```

Comment: In my case the compared number is the private value.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the data before sending to the blockchain. Encryption and decryption should be done off-chain because the blockchain is public and you don't want your plaintext to be exposed.

You can compare those numbers on-chain without exposing your plaintext if you use homomorphic encryption.

> Homomorphic encryption is a form of encryption that allows computation on ciphertexts, generating an encrypted result which, when decrypted, matches the result of the operations as if they had been performed on the plaintext. - Wikipedia